# distinct value of one column based on another column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table structure**

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column 3 | Column 4 . . .. .  Column N

Col1Val1    | Col2Val2    |  . . . . . 
Col1Val1    | Col2Val2    | . . . ..
Col1Val1    | Col2Val3    | . . . . 
Col1Val2    | Col2Val4    | .  . .
Col1Val3    | Col2Val5    | . . 
Col1Val3    | Col2Val6    | . ..
```

I want to query for all the distinct values of column2 for a every distinct value of column1 and its count & values

Example output should be:

```
Col1Val1 | Col2Val2,Col2Val3 | 2
Col1Val2 | Col2Val4          | 1
Col1Val3 | Col2Val5,Col2Val6 | 2
.
.
```

This is pretty much doable from the querying + application handling. 
**Can this/similar output be achieved via only the sql query.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to aggregate and count he distinct `Column2` values:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Column2),
    COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Column1
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: `Group_Concat` by default make distinct selection?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim

Comment: @Tim : group_concat is not making distinct selection by default. Any method to get this done from query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select Column1 , group_concat(distinct column2) ,count(distinct column2)
from your_table 
group by column1
```